# Why does streaming query with Summarizer fail with "requirement failed: Nothing has been added to this summarizer"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

This is a follow-up to [How to generate summary statistics (using Summarizer.metrics) in streaming query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59375053/1305344)

I am running a python script to generate summary statistics of micro-batches of a streaming query.

**Python code** (I am currently running)

```
import sys
import json
import psycopg2
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, to_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object
from pyspark.ml.stat import Summarizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("spark_streaming_sql").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
spark.streams.active

data = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<kafka_broker>:<port_number>").option("subscribe", "<topic_name>").option("startingOffsets", "latest").load()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", DoubleType()),
    StructField("timestamp_value", DoubleType()), 
    StructField("device_id", DoubleType()), 
    StructField("temperature_value", DoubleType()),
    StructField("comment", StringType())])

telemetry_dataframe = data.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("tmp")).select("tmp.*")

telemetry_dataframe.printSchema()

temperature_value_selection = telemetry_dataframe.select("temperature_value")

temperature_value_selection_new = temperature_value_selection.withColumn("device_temperature", temperature_value_selection["temperature_value"].cast(DecimalType()))

temperature_value_selection_new.printSchema()

assembler = VectorAssembler(
  inputCols=["device_temperature"], outputCol="temperatures"
)

assembled = assembler.transform(temperature_value_selection_new)

assembled_new = assembled.withColumn("timestamp", F.current_timestamp())

assembled_new.printSchema()

summarizer = Summarizer.metrics("max", "min", "variance", "mean", "count")

descriptive_table_one = assembled_new.select(summarizer.summary(assembled_new.temperatures))

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#########################################
#               QUERIES                 #
#########################################

query_4_1 = descriptive_table_one.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

For a reason, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Nothing has been added to this summarizer.
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$SummarizerBuffer.max(Summarizer.scala:513)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate$$anonfun$10.apply(Summarizer.scala:582)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate$$anonfun$10.apply(Summarizer.scala:577)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate.eval(Summarizer.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate.eval(Summarizer.scala:567)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.TypedImperativeAggregate.eval(interfaces.scala:543)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateResultProjection$1.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And this causes the abortion of the whole spark job.

Also, keep a note that I generate random data based on a python script. So after the Spark streaming program starts then I also start the data generation. Thus, in Batch:0 I have not data to aggregate-show.

Kindly check my spark logs by following the below link.
[Spark-error logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v6DTCKptBq_mXHivFWzbT_qvsfchlRck/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  Please post.

Comment: @MikePone No, I haven't found any solution to this yet.